# Git pull only certain number of commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull, fast-forward

I have a local git repo and I need to update it. Howhever, the online repo is way ahead of my local copy. I am behind a extremely slow connection. When I use **git pull -v --progress**, I start to see the progress but after a while, I get this error:

```
efrror: RPC failed: result = 18, HTTP code = 200 | 5.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This is due to my very slow connection. I need to know if there is a way to get, say only the first commit ahead of my local repo, to see if I can update my local repo one step at a time.

**Important**: What I would like to know is if there is a way to pull a # of commits ahead of my local copy, not a specific commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pull $N commits of the branch $BRANCH you could do this (assuming that you currently are in $BRANCH):

```
git log $BRANCH..origin/$BRANCH --pretty=format:%H | tail -$N | head -1 | git pull origin
```

Now, step by step:

```
git log $BRANCH..origin/$BRANCH
```

Will give a list of the commits that differ between your local branch and the remote one, and the `--pretty=format:%H` option would just show the commit id, avoiding other information as the author, date or commit message.

```
tail -$N | head -1
```

Given a list, `tail -N` will give you the last N lines of it, and `head -1` will give you the first one. So if we put them both together, we obtain the last Nth line of a list.

```
| git pull origin
```

Will just pull the commit id passed through the pipe into your current branch.